# PHP: mysql query gives a boolean

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
class Page {
    function getPage($urlOfPage){
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT category, title FROM rs-planet WHERE url = "'.  mysql_real_escape_string($urlOfPage));
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) === 0){
            header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
            exit;
        }
        else{
            return $page[] = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And I have this errors:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rs-planet\classes\page.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rs-planet\classes\page.php on line 11
>   And I don't see the problem...

And if I do var_dump @ $result I get a boolean. (If it's founded @ the db it gives true, if it isn't it gives me false.)

PS. Sorry for my bad English, my main language is Dutch.

EDIT:
var_dump(mysql_error) =

> string(152) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '"index' at line 1"

Comment: No closing quotes for the url string value in your SQL query... when will people learn to debug their sql queries, even if they can't be persuaded to enter the 21st century and use prepared statements

Comment: Yup. Prepared statements are a gift from the SQL gods - USE THEM. :)

Comment: Using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), which encourages placeholders, is a really good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_query` returns false if the query cannot be executed (i.e. bad syntax). Try surrounding `rs-planet` with backticks:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT category, title FROM `rs-planet` WHERE url = "'.  mysql_real_escape_string($urlOfPage) . '"');
```

I'm thinking the `-` in the table name is screwing up the syntax.

EDIT: Also, PDO makes it much easier to debug these issues since you don't need to use `mysql_error()` to get the error message - it's included in the Exception thrown by PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

SECOND EDIT: Actually the problem is likely the missing quote. Fixed my code, but see the other answers...

Comment: The query syntax is not fine, it is missing the close quote.

Comment: @citizenen Actually the missing quote is probably the problem, as noted in the other answers.

Comment: @Robin Sorry, had the concat outside the function call; fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns `false` on an error.

You have `WHERE url="` but no closing quote after the url string.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query` returns FALSE on error. Your error is that you are not closing the quote in your query. Try this:

```
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT category, title FROM rs-planet WHERE url = "'.  mysql_real_escape_string($urlOfPage).'"');
```

Comment: Also, try `return $page` instead of `return $page[]`. The former will return the array from `mysql_fetch_array`, the later will return the array from `mysql_fetch_array` in the first element of the `$page` array.